# Where can I find an ADOExpress tutorial?

Tags: delphi, ado

I'm using Delphi 7, totally new to database programming, and need ODBC. I am told that ADOExpress is a good way to go, and that seems fair enough as it comes with Delphi 7.

I need to programatically create, populate, modify and query a database (currently MySql, but that might change, hence ODBC). Can anyone recommend a good tutorial? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mawg, check theses links

- [Build Database Applications with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/Build_Database_Applications_with_Delphi.htm)
- [Working with ADO components (Very complete reference)](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/adocompspart_xml.html)
- [Using ADO in a Delphi application](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/adodelphi.htm)
- [Using Delphi with ADO](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Using-Delphi-with-ADO/)

Comment: Inside the links, there is a nice tutorial called **A Beginner's Guide to Delphi Database Programming** : ... This course focuses on the most common uses of ADO in a Delphi application.
I think I will also read it :)

http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/databasecourse.htm

Answer (score 3):

Well, the original Embarcadero documentation may be interesting too :)

The Delphi 2010 Online Documentation, dbGo/ADO topics:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_ADO_components_Index

Comment: ... and the Delphi 7 PDF Documentation, look there for dbGo/ADO topics:
http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphi7/D7_DevelopersGuide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's called doGo for ADO now by the way, and covered as one of the data access technologies in my http://www.lulu.com/product/2673262 paperback for example.